# OpenSSL signature length is different for a different message

Tags: c++, c, openssl, rsa

I have been struggling with a weird problem with RSA_verify. I am trying to RSA_sign using C and RSA_verify using C++. I have generated the private key and certificate using OpenSSL commands.

```
message = "1.2.0:08:00:27:2c:88:77"
```

When I use the message above, generate a hash and use RSA_sign to sign the digest, I get a signature of length 256 (`strlen(signature)`) and also the length returned from RSA_sign is 256. I use this length to verify and verification succeeds.

But when I use a `message = "1.2.0:08:00:27:2c:88:08"`, the signature length is 60 and RSA_sign returns 256. When I use this length 60 to verify it fails. It fails to verify with length 256 as well. Also for some messages (1.2.0:08:00:27:2c:88:12) the signature generated is zero.

I am using SHA256 to hash the message and NID_SHA256 to RSA_sign and RSA_verify this digest. I have used -sha256 while generating the keys using the OpenSSL command.

I am forming the message by parsing an XML file reading some of the tags using some string operation.

Kindly suggest.

Below is the code used to sign.

```
int main(void)  
{  
    int     ret;  
    RSA    *prikey;  
    char *data ;  
    unsigned char* signature;  
    int slen = 0;  
    FILE * fp_priv = NULL;  
    char* privfilepath = "priv.pem";  
    unsigned char* sign = NULL; 

    ERR_load_crypto_strings();

    data = generate_hash();
    printf("Message after generate hash %s: %d\n", data, strlen(data));

    fp_priv = fopen(privfilepath, "r"); 
    if (fp_priv == NULL)
    {
        printf("Private key path not found..");
        return 1;
    }
    prikey = RSA_new();
    prikey = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp_priv, &prikey, NULL, NULL);
    if (prikey == NULL)
    {
        printf("Private key returned is NULL\n");
        return 1;
    }

    signature = (unsigned char*)malloc(RSA_size(prikey)); 

    if( signature == NULL )
        return 1;

    if(RSA_sign(NID_sha256, (unsigned char*)data, strlen(data), 
         signature, &slen, prikey) != 1) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout); 
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Signature length while signing... %d : %d : %d ",  
       strlen(signature), slen, strlen(data)); 

    FILE * sig_bin = fopen("sig_bin", "w");
    fprintf(sig_bin, "%s", signature);
    fclose(sig_bin);

    system("xxd -p -c256 sig_bin sig_hex"); 

    RSA_free(prikey);
    if(signature)
        free(signature);    
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Without showing your code the question should be closed. However, the output of RSA_sign is *not* a null-terminated character string, so using strlen() on it makes no sense. It may contain embedded 0 bytes at any position. RSA_sign returns the length of the result in another argument.

Answer (score 2):

One very, very important thing to learn about C is it has two distinct types with the same name.

- `char*`: This represents the beginning of a character string. You can do things like strstr or strlen.

  - You should never strstr or strlen, but rather strnstr and strnlen, but that's a different problem.
- `char*`: This represents the beginning of a data blob (aka byte array, aka octet string), you can't meaningfully apply strlen/etc to it.

RSA_sign uses the latter.  It returns "data", not "a message".  So, in your snippet

```
printf("Signature length while signing... %d : %d : %d ",  
   strlen(signature), slen, strlen(data));

FILE * sig_bin = fopen("sig_bin", "w");
fprintf(sig_bin, "%s", signature);
fclose(sig_bin);
```

`data` came from a function called `generate_hash()`; it's probably non-textual, so strlen doesn't apply. `signature` definitely is data, so strlen doesn't apply.  fprintf also doesn't apply, for the same reasons.  These functions identify the end of the character string by the first occurrence of a zero-byte (0x00, '\0', etc).  But 0x00 is perfectly legal to have in a signature, or a hash, or lots of "data".

The length of the output of RSA_sign is written into the address passed into the 5th parameter.  You passed `&slen` (address-of slen), so once the function exits (successfully) `slen` is the length of the signature.  Note that it will only very rarely match strlen(signature).

To write your signature as binary, you should use [fwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/), such as `fwrite(sig_bin, sizeof(char), signature, slen);`.  If you want it as text, you should [Base-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encode your data.

Comment: Yes Thanks a lot bartonjs. That is the problem :)